# What is the purpose of the Account and Manage controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I create a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project with the "Individual User Account" as authentication option, an Account and a Manage controller created. I know both are relevant for authentication and security.

But what is the main purpose of each of these controller files? What is the reason and responsibility for each one?

Answer (score 1):

`AccountController` and `ManageController` controller contains the sample code for **Membership and Authorization**. Which provided by default on project creation because its common stuff for web application and its help full to all for beginners, Intermediate and Experts also. From those controller you can manage/ create `Role Based` application more easily and quickly.